# Firefox not showing blank page

Tags: firefox

For some reason half the time firefox shows tabs/pages when I last had it open. Even though I tell it to use blank pages and made it use homepage (close/open) and set back to blank page (closed and reopened it). Half the time it shows a blank page like i selected the other half it shows the last few tabs/pages.

Is there any way to fix this? I believe it happened starting this version (21) and i been checking for an update weekly hoping for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I have my Startup options set up as shown below and it works for me 100% of the time:

[image: 1]

If you want you can also open **about:config** and set **browser.newtab.url** to **about:blank** as well.

Comment: Well that's annoying because that's exactly what I have

Comment: What I fail to understand is why it would be so inconsistent. Perhaps it's due to a bad extension, so try disabling them all. Also try starting afresh with no remnants of your existing profile.

Comment: Good idea. The moment it happens again i'll try to reproduce it and try extensions. I have more then one profile so the others will few addons might help me narrow it down

Comment: I figured out two things. 1) It happens when I have no addons 2) It happens on more then one profile. I have 3 and I can confirm it happens on two of the three (the one i have addons is the only one i havent confirmed but its the one i close the least). Also when it happens closing/opening doesn't trigger it so it doesnt seem to have to do with the amount of tabs or page